# Error from trying to get the json response [Flutter]

Tags: json, flutter, android-studio, dart

I've tried to call the data by trying to get the json response from the server.

```
Future<List<Users>> getUserLogin() async{
  String url= login_url;
  var res = await http.get(url);

  if(res.statusCode==200){
    var list = json.decode(res.body) as List;  
    print(list);
    List<Users> users =  list.map((i)=>Users.fromJson(i)).toList();
    print(users);
    return users;
  }
  else{
    print("bad request");
  }
}
```

However, I got this error message and was not able to get the data.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
```

By the way, this is the json data that I tried to call.

```
{"customer_id":4,
"username":"aa",
"password":"bb",
"firstname":"a",
"lastname":"b",
"birthday":"Feb 15, 2021",
"phone":"906583794",
"cus_email":"aaa@gmail.com"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response object that you have delivered, you must modify the type of data that returns from a list to a user, because this json that you expect is not an array but an object.

With this explained, you should:

1. Modify the return type of the function:

   `Future<User> getUserLogin() async {...}`
2. After validating an OK response (200) try this:

   `return User user = User.fromJson(res.body);`

Comment: Hi,I've just tried but there is an error at the word "res.body" as:

"Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'."

Comment: Try this: `return User user = User.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));`

Comment: It returned " Instance of 'Users' " and the data is still null 

Comment: Could you provide the response to the request? The value of "res.body"

Comment: According to your question, I also tried to print the res.body of another existing function and I just found that I can use that function to call the data. Sorry for my mistake.  However, I still have another question. I will post the question and the function as another answer.

Comment: @user15254342 I did not understand the question very well, do you want that function to return Users?

If that is the case, you must modify the return data type of the function, today that function returns a boolean.

If you want the user to return, you must modify the data type of the function in this way:

Future <Users> checkLogin (String username, String password) async {...}

and then replace the return, today you return true or false, you must replace this Boolean value with your Users variable, it would look like this:

return users;

Comment: I will try this solution. Thank you so much. ☺️

Answer (score 0):

How can I return the data I've got into "users" because it's still json data and if I return more than 1 time, another will be dead code.

Function:

```
  Future<bool> checkLogin(String username,String password) async {
  if(username.isEmpty||password.isEmpty){
    print("Invalid username or password");
    return false;
  }
  String url = login_url;
  url = url.replaceFirst("p1", username);
  url = url.replaceFirst("p2", password);
  var result = await http.get(url);
  var data = json.decode(result.body);
  if(username==data["username"]&&password==data["password"]){
    print(result.body);
    Users users = Users.fromJson(json.decode(result.body));
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

result.body:

```
{"customer_id":4,"username":"aa","password":"bb","firstname":"a","lastname":"b","birthday":"Feb 15, 2021","phone":"906583794","cus_email":"aaa@gmail.com"}
```